# How to get index of element by unique class "active"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some very simple code to get information about active div with class name active. I currently trying to get its index between a collection of divs with class name slide. However, I tried many selectors with no benefit. So, I need your help.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

.slide {
    width:50px;border:1px solid #808080;height:50px;float:left; display:inline-block;
    text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;/*display:none;*/
}
.active { background-color:brown }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <input id="get_info" type="button" value="<<>>" /> 

    <br />
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="slide ">0</div>
            <div class="slide">1</div>
            <div class="slide active">2</div>
            <div class="slide">3</div>
        </div>
    <br />
    <p id="msg"></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var nxt = 0;
        var prv = 0;
        var crnt = 0;

        $("#get_info").click(function () {
            crnt = $(".slide").index(".slide .active");
            $('#msg').html(crnt);
        });

    });
</script>
```

As shown all I need to get "active" position index between "slide". The permanent result for this is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $("#get_info").click(function() {
    let crnt = $(".slide").index($(".slide.active"));
    $('#msg').html(crnt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <input id="get_info" type="button" value="<<>>" /> 

    <br />
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="slide ">0</div>
            <div class="slide">1</div>
            <div class="slide active">2</div>
            <div class="slide">3</div>
        </div>
    <br />
    <p id="msg"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please explain or add a reference to what is "let".  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA  In short, let is another option to declare a variable instead of using var. Full explanation e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA And for a reference check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let